# How can I align my paragraph content and heading content to be underneath the date? float:right doesn't work

Tags: html, css

My aim is to align the heading and the content underneath the date. I tried using float:right and play with margins and padding but it doesn't seem to work

```
     <div class="content container_12">
         <ul id="list-content">
                <li> <img src="images/img_thumbnail1.png" alt="inferno cape">
                    <!-- <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="text-content">Game Updates | January 1st, 2017</time> -->
                    <h2 class="header-content text-content">This is a heading</h2>
                    <p class="paragraph-content text-content">This is the content</p>
                </li>
                <li> <img src="images/img_thumbnail2.png" alt="find option">
                    <!-- <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="paragraph-content text-content">Game Updates | November 17th 2016</time> -->
                </li>
                <li> <img src="images/img_thumbnail3.png" alt="duel arena">
                    <!-- <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="paragraph-content text-content">Game Updates | October 17th 2015</time> -->
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

*This is my css* any idea what could've caused this?/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
.content {
  background-color: #3d4b5b;
}

#list-content li img {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.text-content{
  float: right;
  margin:0;
}

.header-content {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0;
}

.paragraph-content{
  float: right;
}

time{
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin:0;
}
```

[image: image of my current result]

Comment: Can you provide some expected behaviour image? "underneath the date" is  a bit vague.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f4r9hf This is what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expected behaviour image, here is the code snippet to implement what you want. Basically, you need to:

1. wrap heading & time & paragraph into one container (`.desc`).
2. float image to left and float `.desc` to right (I guess this is what you want, but if you want to put image and `.desc` near each other, you can float `.desc` to left).
3. use `clear:both` on `:after` pseudo element of `li`, to give `li` element height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  background-color: #3d4b5b;
}
#list-content li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
#list-content li img {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#list-content li .desc {
  float: right;
}
#list-content li .desc .text-content {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}
#list-content li:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
     <div class="content container_12">
         <ul id="list-content">
                <li> 
                  <img src="https://img1.doubanio.com/lpic/s27653128.jpg" alt="inferno cape">
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h2 class="header-content text-content">This is a heading</h2>
                    <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="text-content">Game Updates | January 1st, 2017</time>
                    <p class="paragraph-content text-content">This is the content</p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="https://img3.doubanio.com/lpic/s4554820.jpg" alt="find option">
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h2 class="header-content text-content">This is a heading</h2>
                    <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="text-content">Game Updates | January 1st, 2017</time>
                    <p class="paragraph-content text-content">This is the content</p>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li> 
                  <img src="https://img3.doubanio.com/lpic/s8958650.jpg" alt="duel arena">
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h2 class="header-content text-content">This is a heading</h2>
                    <time datetime="2017-01-01" class="text-content">Game Updates | January 1st, 2017</time>
                    <p class="paragraph-content text-content">This is the content</p>
                  </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/s7zf0e3x/) is also made for reference.

Comment: Ye that was good man, but I managed to solve this by using the flex property and also adding a list item to each new element and it solved my problem as well :D cheers though :)) that's exactly the result I wanted ^^